# vFAT maximum data allowed 4gb?

Tags: hard-drive, vfat

how much data can be store on a FAT virtual drive? I know that a file can be max. 4gb on a vFAT but does that mean I can only store 4gb max on that drive?

Comment: "how much data can be store on a FAT virtual drive?" - Are we talking FAT12, FAT16, or FAT32?  I will be unable to submit my answer until you provide me an answer to this question.

Comment: did you see tons of 8 or 16GB flash drive out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Does that mean I can only store 4gb max on that drive?**

The maximum volume sizd is based on if your using FAT12, FAT16, or FAT32.  I am going to assume your using FAT32 based on the fact you are talking about 4 GiB files.

Additionally, VFAT is an extension of the File Allocation Table (FAT) file system architecture standard, it is NOT a file system itself.

> **how much data can be store on a FAT virtual drive?**

This entire depends if the file system if FAT16 or FAT32.  FAT16 is going to limit you to 4 GiB volume size while FAT32 will limit you to 2 TiB volume size.  It is worth pointing out that the currently supported versions of Windows only support FAT32 and exFAT.

> ### What About VFAT?
>
> Perhaps you've also heard of a file system called VFAT. VFAT is an
>   extension of the FAT file system and was introduced with Windows 95.
>   VFAT maintains backward compatibility with FAT but relaxes the rules.
>   For example, VFAT filenames can contain up to 255 characters, spaces,
>   and multiple periods. Although VFAT preserves the case of filenames,
>   it's not considered case sensitive.
>
> When you create a long filename (longer than 8.3) with VFAT, the file
>   system actually creates two different filenames. One is the actual
>   long filename. This name is visible to Windows 95, Windows 98, and
>   Windows NT (4.0 and later). The second filename is called an MS-DOS®
>   alias. An MS-DOS alias is an abbreviated form of the long filename.
>   The file system creates the MS-DOS alias by taking the first six
>   characters of the long filename (not counting spaces), followed by the
>   tilde [~] and a numeric trailer. For example, the filename Brien's
>   Document.txt would have an alias of BRIEN'~1.txt.
>
> An interesting side effect results from the way VFAT stores its long
>   filenames. When you create a long filename with VFAT, it uses one
>   directory entry for the MS-DOS alias and another entry for every 13
>   characters of the long filename. In theory, a single long filename
>   could occupy up to 21 directory entries. The root directory has a
>   limit of 512 files, but if you were to use the maximum length long
>   filenames in the root directory, you could cut this limit to a mere 24
>   files. Therefore, you should use long filenames very sparingly in the
>   root directory. Other directories aren't affected by this limit.
>
> You may be wondering why we're discussing VFAT. The reason is it's
>   becoming more common than FAT, but aside from the differences I
>   mentioned above, VFAT has the same limitations. When you tell Windows
>   NT to format a partition as FAT, it actually formats the partition as
>   VFAT. The only time you'll have a true FAT partition under Windows NT
>   4.0 is when you use another operating system, such as MS-DOS, to format the > > partition.

Source: [Choosing Between File Systems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750354.aspx)

Additionally

> Further, the term "VFAT" has led to various misconceptions as well,
>   as it is sometimes erroneously used as if it would describe another
>   variant of FAT file system to be distinguished from the FAT12, FAT16
>   and FAT32 file systems, while in reality it does not specify another
>   file system, but an optional extension, which can work on top of any
>   FAT file system, FAT12, FAT16 or FAT32. Volumes utilizing VFAT
>   long-filenames can be read also by operating systems not supporting
>   the VFAT extension, for as long as they support the underlying file
>   system.

Source: [File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)